# Is there a way to provide a starred variant of a (xkeyval) boolean (class) option

Tags: catcodes, starred-version, xkeyval

I'd like to define, for a class I'm working on, two boolean keys rather similar and, instead of giving them different names, I'd like to let the latter be a starred variant of the former.

Let me give an example with a minimal class file which defines such a starred boolean value. By changing the catcode of the `*` character into `11`, I managed to make it work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@boolkey{myclass.cls}[MYC@]{land*}[false]{}
\ProcessOptionsX
\LoadClass{article}
\begingroup
\catcode`\*=11\relax
\ifMYC@land*
\endgroup
\RequirePackage[landscape]{geometry}
\else
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[land*=true]{myclass}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

but it is unstable as it only works with the `true` value. With the `false` value, I get an error involving `\providecommand*` which is clearly unknown if `*` is a letter.

Hence my question: how could I define a robust starred variant of a  (xkeyval) boolean (class) option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\@nameuse`

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myclass.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@boolkey{myclass.cls}[MYC@]{land*}[false]{}
\ProcessOptionsX
\LoadClass{article}
\@nameuse{ifMYC@land*}
  \RequirePackage[landscape]{geometry}
\else
  \RequirePackage{geometry}
\fi
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass[land*=true]{myclass}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was soooo simple! ;)